# Implicit conversion is not called

Tags: c#, reflection, implicit-conversion

I have two objects: `Obj` and `ObjViewModel`. `ObjViewModel` has a method inside of it that looks like this:

```
public static implicit operator ObjViewModel(Obj o)
{
  //Code to do the conversion here
}
```

I have a reflection method later that ends up running in to a situation where it needs to copy a `List<obj>` to a `List<objViewModel>`. That code looks like this:

```
foreach(var p in propertyPairs)
{
  if (p.ViewModel.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Count(i => i.Name == "IList") > 0)
  {
    p.ViewModel.SetValue(ret, Activator.CreateInstance(p.ViewModel.PropertyType));
    foreach (var v in (IList)p.Model.GetValue(m))
    {
      ((IList)p.ViewModel.GetValue(ret)).Add(v);
    }
  }
  else
    p.ViewModel.SetValue(ret, p.Model.GetValue(m));
```

The problem is, when I get to `((IList)p.ViewModel.GetValue(ret)).Add(v);` the implicit conversion is never called on v and the code crashes because v is of type `obj` and the list is looking for `objViewModel`. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your questions, but here are two comments: `Obj` is a really bad name for a type if you ask me. Couldn't you find a name that at least tries to describe what the type is for? Use `Any` instead of `Count` if you just want to know if a collection has any items.

Comment: I abstracted away the names because there are actually several pairs of classes that all follow this pattern, but good catch on the any/count thing

Answer (score 0):

You have an expression of compile-time type (because of your cast) non-generic `IList`. The `Add` method of the non-generic `IList` takes a `System.Object`. So:

```
((IList)something).Add(v);
```

will just need `v` to be convertible to `System.Object`. So the C# compiler will not insert a call to your user-defined conversion.

Even if the conversion is `implicit` you can call it explicitly, as in:

```
((IList)something).Add((ObjViewModel)v);
```

Another possibility that might work (I am not sure what type you have behind the scenes) is:

```
((IList<ObjViewModel>)something).Add(v);
```

which requires that `something` actually implements `IList<ObjViewModel>`. This `Add` method is another one that takes an argument of type `ObjViewModel`, so the C# compiler will search for and find your user-defined conversion and emit IL code that calls it on `v`.

Comment: There are actually something like 18 pairs of types that all follow this same pattern, so I don't actually know what the types are going to be till run time.

Comment: @pquest But when you use non-generic interface `IList`, everything will be of compile-time type object. Then C# compiler will not see a need to insert a call to your conversion. Maybe you can rewrite your code to use generics?

Comment: is the only requirement that the types are not the same? If all the obj classes were to inherit from some base class `baseObj` and the other classes inherited from `vmObj` (which they already do) would that be enough to make this work?